# Is there a way to create a custom edit flag in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, editing

I moderate a wiki where many users use the AutoWikiBrowser to rapidly edit. This is fine but it makes it harder to locate and deal with vandalism via the recent changes. Is there any way that I can create a custom edit flag to mark edits as semi-automated and allow users to hide them from the recent changes? Ideally this would come with the ability to mark edits as semi-automated by default, which would allow the functionality I seek without needing a change to the AWB source code.

The ability to mark one's edits as semi-automated shouldn't be open to anyone, so it would need to be restricted to certain usergroups (probably rollback and up). I realise that there is the ability to mark edits as bot edits, but this is inaccurate as they are not truly bots, and inconvenient, since it requires a bureaucrat to mark the user as a bot, then unmark them when their editing is finished. I realise its a lot to request, and I certainly understand if its not possible, but I was hoping that it was.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have users use two accounts - one for manual edits and one for bot edits? Or is that too much overhead for the users?

As you say, if your bots have their own accounts you can add them to the bot group. Then users can, in Recent Changes, decide themselves to show / hide bot edits.

Then your admins can patrol the changes as usual.

Comment: That has been discussed and it has been suggested that it is an irritation for users to have to sign into a different account any time they wish to do some AWB editing, then sign back into their old account when they are finished. Additionally the edits are not truly automated as a bot flag would imply. So while a bot account would work in this case, its not how they were intended to be used. Still, if it winds up being impossible to do as I asked, then that will likely be what we wind up doing.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it might lead to more overhead - but I don't have any other ideas. Bear in mind, of course, that the big selling point of a wiki is that it is **low threshold**. Implementing this solution will increase the threshold for editing significantly which may mean people either *don't* do this correctly or *stop editing*!

Comment: Is this still a live issue Jon? Did you ask for help on the AWB page at Wikipedia? I'm sure someone there will have dealt with this issue before. If not and you still need help I can make some enquiries. (I'm a semi-retired AWB dev).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple: add a user group whose users are able to add and remove themselves (via Special:userrights) to the default "bot" group or to another group "flood" having only the "bot" and perhaps "noratelimit" permission; then add those users to this group.